# Inconsistent register values after setting up them in a Jprobes module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, cpu-registers, kprobe

This question is in continuation to my previous question on [Intercepting ELF loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797827/intercept-elf-loader-in-linux-kernel-fs-binfmt-elf-c-file-via-loadable-kernel-m).

Now the exact problem is that previously the code logic was implemented within the `load_elf_binary` function wherein at the end of the function `eax, ebx, ecx and edx` registers were set via an inline asm call, just before the function returned.

I have planted a `jprobe` on the `load_elf_binary` function as I need to access the `struct linux_binprm *bprm` argument but since I set the register values within the jprobe handler it causes an inconsistency when the control returns to the actual function and the application terminates with a segmentation fault.

What could be a possible solution to this ?

Comment: Could you post your code that sets the Jprobes as well as the code of the probe handler here? It would be easier for the kernel experts to suggest something this way.

Comment: Implementation within kernel: http://pastebin.com/gxmmdkDa  JProbes module implementation: http://pastebin.com/hF7d540x  The implementation within the kernel works fine but not when implented via JProbes.